Spring batch issue with multiple datasource | spring boot 3
I am facing an issue with spring batch job in a monolith application. In that application two different module have different databases and we need to write batch job in both the module.
Now, since spring batch job expect a datasource bean with name datasource , it is getting impossible to write 2 batch jobs in single deployable application, within  two different module connecting to different databases.
I think spring batch has discontinued the batchconfigurer class which I can see as a possible solution in some stackoverflow answers.
Spring boot 3 is what I am using and spring batch is 5.1.x

In Spring Boot 3, you can mark the datasource that you want to use for Spring Batch with @BatchDataSource. Even if you have multiple datasources, the one marked with that annotation will be used for Spring Batch.

But, if two batch job runs in two module with different databases , there will be only 1 bean with annotation BatchDataSource. Since it's one app two bean can't be created annotated with BatchDatasource

Sorry, but I don't understand your setup. Please edit your question and share the code you use and all the needed details to help you efficiently.

We are able to solve it by using EnableBatchProcessing with dataSourceRef .Thanks @mahmoud

Oh great to hear that! Thank you.
